# Force Chrome Password Manager to save an extension password

Tags: google-chrome, security, google-chrome-extensions

I'm trying to force Chrome to save a password for an [extension URL like this](http://chrome-extension://dmkamcknogkgcdfhhbddcghachkejeap/popup.html#/register) but I can't make it work. Chrome refuses to prompt saving of password likely because this is an extension URL with the protocol `chrome-extension`. I've tried the flags:

- unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure
- allow-insecure-localhost

But none of those worked. This is the only thing holding me back from using Chrome's password manager.
Any help in the right direction will be greatly appreciated

Comment: What's the "an extension URL **like this**"?

Comment: @harrymc updated the missing link

Comment: Chrome's password manager is much less evolved than third-party ones. For example [Bitwarden](https://bitwarden.com/). In fact, most password managers keep password when you login, rarely when you create the account.